# Why can't I type text on the screen while using the key.get_pressed feature of pygame?

Tags: python, text, pygame

When I type in this program I want the letters that I am typing to show up on the screen. However, when I try and type nothing appears on the screen. How do I fix this issue since it works when I replace the keys[KDOWN] feature with the event.type == KDOWN feature.

```
from pygame import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode((800, 600))

name_font = font.Font(None, 32)
name_text = ''


while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for events in event.get():
        keys = key.get_pressed()
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()
        if keys[KEYDOWN]:
            name_text += events.unicode
    text_surface = name_font.render(name_text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (50, 50))


    display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `get_pressed`, you need to check every key. It's better to check the KEYDOWN event and get the pressed key.

Try this code:

```
from pygame import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode((800, 600))

name_font = font.Font(None, 32)
name_text = ''


while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for events in event.get():
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()
        if events.type == KEYDOWN:
            name_text += events.unicode
    text_surface = name_font.render(name_text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (50, 50))

    display.update()
```